# Looking for a method to maximize an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I need a method to find a positive real valued function $x(t)$ that maximizes the following integral:

$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty} f\left(\frac{dx}{dt},t\right)\;dt
$$
such that $x(0)=0$, $\lim_{t\to \infty}x(t)=N$ and $f$ is a given function.

Comment: The [Euler-Lagrange equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) of the integral $\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{x}} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0$ tells us $\frac{\partial f(\dot{x}(t),t)}{\partial \dot{x}}$ is independent of $t$. This gives you a non-linear first order ODE in $x(x)$. You just solve it and then find the solution which satisfy the given initial conditions.

Comment: @achillehui: thank you for the idea. Following the mentioned steps, in the case where we have $f\left(\frac{dx}{dt},t\right)=g(t)\frac{dx}{dt}-h(t)\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2$, I arrived at the equation 
 $g(t)-2h(t)\frac{dx}{dt}=a\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)$. Then, I just stuck in finding  the function $a$ that satisfies the initial conditions...

Comment: $a$ is not a function in $\dot{x}$, it is an integration constant! Integrating the ODE and using the condition $x(0) = 0$, you get $$x(t) = \int_0^t \frac{g(\tau) - a}{2h(\tau)} d\tau$$ The condition $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x(t) = N$ becomes
$$
2N = \int_0^\infty \frac{g(\tau)-a}{h(\tau)} d\tau
\quad\implies\quad a = 
\frac{\int_0^\infty \frac{g(\tau)}{h(\tau)}d\tau - 2N}{\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{h(\tau)}d\tau}$$